# How to exclude 0 from all ranges in this formula?

Tags: excel-formula

I need to exclude 0's from the following formula. Can you please advise:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(IF(B5:B55>K12,B5:B55-K12))*1/COUNT(B5:B55)/SQRT(SUM(IF(B5:B55<K12,(B5:B55-K12)^2)*1/COUNT(B5:B55))),"ERROR")
```

Comment: Do you mean that if there is a cell with value zero in the range b5:b55 it should not be considered?

Comment: @cte6 Hi, yes that's correct.

Comment: Since most of your calculations are already filtering based on the value of k12, you probably only need to filter the count(b5:b55) which you can change to be a countif(b5:b55,">0")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I did it properly but give it a try...

I divided your original Array formula into two parts:

```
=SUM(IF(B5:B55>K12,B5:B55-K12))*1/COUNT(B5:B55)
=SUM(IF(B5:B55<K12,(B5:B55-K12)^2)*1/COUNT(B5:B55))
```

Equivalent "zero-proof" formulas will be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$5:$B$55-$K$12,--($B$5:$B$55>$K$12),--($B$5:$B$55<>0))*1/COUNTIF($B$5:$B$55,"<>"&0)
=SUMPRODUCT((($B$5:$B$55-$K$12)^2)*1/COUNTIF($B$5:$B$55,"<>"&0),--($B$5:$B$55<$K$12),--($B$5:$B$55<>0))
```

Combined:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$5:$B$55-$K$12,--($B$5:$B$55>$K$12),--($B$5:$B$55<>0))*1/COUNTIF($B$5:$B$55,"<>"&0)/SQRT(SUMPRODUCT((($B$5:$B$55-$K$12)^2)*1/COUNTIF($B$5:$B$55,"<>"&0),--($B$5:$B$55<$K$12),--($B$5:$B$55<>0)))
```

Final result looks like that:

[image]

...and when I add some zeros to the data set it looks like that:

[image]

Comment: Yup, it was indeed. :) Thanks. Take care.